# routing module angular

Tags: angular, routing

estoy queriendo crear una app que tenga unas cards y un navbar (simplemente para ver como queda lo hice) y tengo un routing module con varios importados. Ahora el tema es que el componente home me funciona pero el "heroes" no. Dejo codigo.

La idea es que del home, puedas ir a cada seccion y por ejemplo traiga (por una api o cualquier cosa) muchos heroes y mapearlos. Ya no se que mas pones que pueda ayudar, cualquier duda pregunten y gracias de antemano

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule),
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    loadChildren: () => import('./heroes/heroes.module').then(m => m.HeroesModule),
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { NavbarComponent } from './common/navbar/navbar.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

home-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeIndexComponent } from './home-index/home-index.component';
import { HomeRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';
import { CardComponent } from './components/card/card.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeIndexComponent,
    CardComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HomeRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

home-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeIndexComponent } from './home-index/home-index.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeIndexComponent ,
  }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class HomeRoutingModule {}
```

home-index.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-index',
  templateUrl: './home-index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-index.component.css']
})
export class HomeIndexComponent {

}
```

el de heroes
heroes.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HeroesIndexComponent } from './heroes-index/heroes-index.component';
import { HeroesRoutingModule } from './heroes-routing.module';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HeroesIndexComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HeroesRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
})
export class HeroesModule { }
```

heroes-routing.module.ts

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HeroesIndexComponent } from "./heroes-index/heroes-index.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'heroes',
    component: HeroesIndexComponent,
  }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class HeroesRoutingModule {}
```

y el ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes-index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes-index.component.css']
})
export class HeroesIndexComponent {

}
```

Comment: El path de heroes sería `heroes/heroes/`, aún así no muestra nada?, por otro lado agrega un `{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'heroes'}` para ver si accede al segundo routing.